# How wait several requests are resolved to send an response in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, callback, synchronized

I need to do the the same request to external api with differents parameter (node.js and express.js)
If all answers to my requests are correct, then I send the angular client code 200, however, if any erroneous send him the error.
I try something like that but don't work:

```
for(var i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
github.repos.createHook({

                    user: user,
                    repo: array[i],
                    name: "web",
                    config: {

                        url: "http://9ec2067d.ngrok.io/api/v1/callback",
                        content_type: "json"
                    },
                    events: ["*"],
                    active:true,

                    headers: {
                        "X-GitHub-OTP": "two-factor-code"
                    }


                }, function(err, res) {
                    if (err) {

                        console.log(err);
                        errGithub = true;
                        response.status(404).json(err);


                    }
                    else {
                        if(i==array.length && !errGithub){


                            response.json({message:"OK"});

                        }


                    }
```

Any idea?
Many thanks

Comment: `i` never go to array.length, try `i == array.length - 1`. `createHook` is synchronous ?

Comment: Not a NODE.js guy, but I think you can easily do this with some kind of deffer mechanism at the backend. And if you are okay, you can handle this completely on your front-end (Angular) by chaining out http promises

Comment: No, is asynchronous, and I think i == array.length - 1 not work, because the loop ends before it have become the requests. I am not sure.

Comment: How I can concatenate promises like this? .then( function(result){
            defered.resolve(result);
          },
          function (err) {
            defered.reject(err);
          });
        return promise;

Comment: Use tools like [Async](https://github.com/caolan/async) who handle parallelism

Comment: yep, you should use Async or Promises for these kinda tasks

Comment: I will try it. Many thanks.

Comment: I have shown that this method of Async  maybe work: async.waterfall, but I don't understand where and when I get the result if it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try this out:**

```
// Include the async package
// Make sure you add "async" to your package.json
async = require("async");

// 1st para in async.each() is the array of items
async.each(array,
  // 2nd param is the function that each item is passed to
  function(item, callback){
    // Call an asynchronous function,
    github.repos.createHook({

                    user: user,
                    repo: item,
                    name: "web",
                    config: {

                        url: "http://9ec2067d.ngrok.io/api/v1/callback",
                        content_type: "json"
                    },
                    events: ["*"],
                    active:true,

                    headers: {
                        "X-GitHub-OTP": "two-factor-code"
                    }

                }, function(err, res) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        errGithub = true;
                    }
                    callback(); //required
                });
  },

  // 3rd param is the function to call when everything's done
  function(err){

    if(err){
      console.log('Error:' + err);
    }

    // All tasks are done now
    if(errGithub ===true){
      response.status(404).json(err);
    }else{
      response.json({message:"OK"});
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i will try it :D

Comment: this method, sometimes, returned timeout errors, other people have told me that it might be better to try with eachseries () method, because I want to wait the response of external server before send other request. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Promises, it is a clean and easy way to do it.

First create a queue with promises:

```
   var queue = array.map((item) => { 
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        github.repos.createHook({ 
            user: user,
            repo: item, 
            name: "web",
            config: {
                url: "http://9ec2067d.ngrok.io/api/v1/callback",
                content_type: "json"
            },
            events: ["*"],
            active:true,
            headers: {
                "X-GitHub-OTP": "two-factor-code"
            }
        }, (err, res) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err)
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                resolve(res);
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Then execute it:

```
Promise.all(queue).then((values) => { 
    response.json({message:"OK"}) 
},(err) => {
    response.status(404).json(err)
});
```

- This example just explains how you could use promises, the code has not been tested.
- check also the documentation on: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all